# Bootstrap v4 tooltip (tether) isn't working (angular2)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, tooltip, bootstrap-4

I've read the instructions from  https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/tooltips/

I'm using a bundle config for my scripts, here's how they're coming through::
[image]

**EDIT**
Just realized that we have kendo.bootstrap.Theme/all.css included as well. Removed it, still see the same issues.

Here's the reference from the nav bar::

```
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <div class="navbar-nav">
                    <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Reports coming soon">
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled">Reports</a>
                    </span>
                    <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Admin coming soon">
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled">Admin</a>
                    </span>
                </div>
```

This gives me a regular tool tip when I use it with ::

```
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
            });
```

This initialization (found during my many google searches) shows a new tool tip, but not the expected black one. It's a transparent orange?

```
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("body").tooltip({
                    selector: "[data-toggle='tooltip']",
                    container: "body"
                })
            });
```

[image]

I'm SUPER confused what I'm doing wrong. I don't see any errors on my console and I've read over the bootstrap documentation about a dozen times. If I left off needed info, I'm sorry, and lmk.

Thanks,

Comment: well, have you checked its styles? Maybe there is some css overriding the default ones?

Comment: I just did, I removed every stray reference to tooltip (a rogue css I wasn't aware of) and I still have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Crash called it, that and browser caching. I'm all set, thanks!